# Decrease Runtime of Copying Macro - Load into Array to decrease runtime? Other Suggestions?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, runtime, copying

So I made a copying-macro that goes through a list of Worksheets and copies data from it to another worksheet. Im using assignments, no Selections or Activiations  and turn ScreenUpdating and so on off at the beginning, but it still takes relatively long (about 25 seconds) to just copy text into other cells. Ive read that loading the text I want to copy into an array at first, so that its in RAM, in order to make it run way quicker. Sadly, I couldnt get it to work with my existing Code. If you can help me to do this or have any other suggestions to make this run quicker, I would greatly appreciate it! Heres my whole code, main looping segment that does all the work and takes all the time is towards the middle:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim lr As Integer
Dim SpaltenIndex As Integer
Dim SheetNummer As Integer
Dim cl As range
Dim rw As range
Dim Antwortrange As String
Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
Dim WrkShtCol As Sheets
Dim HandlungsempfehlungsSpalte As String


'Prep 
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Application.Calculation = xlManual
   Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clipboard leeren
   
   
   
'Starting Preperations (New Sheet to copy to, change name etc, doesnt take much time I think..)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Auswertung").Select
'Create new Worksheet
Sheets.Add
'Change Name of new WS
ActiveSheet.Name = "Handlungsempfehlungen"
'Change column size
Columns("A:Z").ColumnWidth = 95.86
Columns("AA:AZ").ColumnWidth = 95.86
'Possible answer range to search through
Antwortrange = "C11:F400" 'Maybe too big? 
'New WS Title
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen")


SpaltenIndex = 1
SheetNummer = 1

'List of all Worksheets I want to go through and copy stuff from:

Set WrkShtCol = Worksheets(Array("AM AD - Anforderungsdefinition", "AM AA - Anforderunganalyse", "AM - Anforderungsdokumentation", "AM AV - Anforderungsvalidierung", "TM IT - Initiierung Test", "TM ZD - Zieldefinition", "TM TV - Testvorgehen", "TM TOB - Testobjektabgrenzung", "TM AS - Aufwandsschätzung", "TM TP - Testplanung", "TM TP - Testplanung", "TM TS - Teststeuerung", "TM TK - Testkontrolle", "TM AO - Aufbauorganisation", "TM RM - Risikomanagement", "TM MI - Managementinformation", "TM AF - Abnahme Freigabe", "TM AT - Abschluss Test", "DT IT - Installationstest", "DT ST - Sicherheitstest", "OTP DT - Dokumententest", "OTP MT - Modultest", "OTP MIT - Modulintegrationstest", "OTP OO KT - OO Klassentest", "OTP OO KIT - OO Klassenintgrate", "OTP FT - Funktionstest", "OTP FIT - Funktionsintgratiotes", "OTP PIT - Produktintegratest", "OTP AT - Abnahmetest", "OTP ET - Ergonomietest", "OTP LPT - Last & Performance", "OTP GPT - Geschäftsprozesstest", "TUP TMK -Testumg Module Klassen", _
"TUP TUF - Testumgebung Funktion", "TUP TP - Testumgebung Prozesse", "ATP KM Konfigurationsmanagement", "ATP FAEM - Fehler Änderungs", "ATP DS - Datensicherheit", "ATP DSCH - Datenschutz", "ATP TEV -Testergebnisverwaltung", "ATP VG - Vertragsgestaltung"))
    

'MAIN Looping Segment for Copying What I need (Values of the cells 9 columns to the right of the cells that have an "x" as their value)


For Each WrkSht In WrkShtCol

    For Each rw In WrkSht.range(Antwortrange).Rows   'Reihen durchlaufen innerhalb der Antwortrange
    For Each cl In rw.Cells
        
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, SpaltenIndex).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    If lr = 2 And ws.range("A1") = "" Then lr = 1
    'If lr = 2 And ws.Range("A2") = "" Then lr = 1
       
            If LCase(cl.Value) = "x" Then
                cl.Offset(0, 9).Copy Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(lr, SpaltenIndex)     
            End If
        Next cl
    Next rw



'If Row 1 empty, delete and shift towards top so there are no gaps

If Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(1, SpaltenIndex) = "" Then Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(1, SpaltenIndex).Delete Shift:=xlUp

'WrkShtCol(1).range("A2").Copy Worksheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cell(lr, SpaltenIndex)

Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(35, SpaltenIndex).Value = WrkShtCol(SheetNummer).Cells(2, 1)


'Change Font
With Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(35, SpaltenIndex)
Schrift der Überschrift (Zeile 35) zentrieren, vergrößern etc, schnellerer Überblick
.Font.Bold = True
.Font.Size = 12
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

SpaltenIndex = SpaltenIndex + 1
SheetNummer = SheetNummer + 1


Next WrkSht

'Preperations back to normal
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

PS: Maybe the range I search through for the value "x" (C11:F400) is too big? I could dim this down I think..

Comment: Take a look at the late Chip Pearson's page on [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for information as how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I will! This also works with a single Cell when not using a Range? Or probably just declaring the range as one cell? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use a One-Dimension-Array with some Textfunctions.
Something like the following Code.

Well. It is better to use a moredimensional Array. But its a little bit more complex. You can also use just Redim Newarray(0) and write Redim Preserver Newarray(i) in the loop.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Integer.
.
.
.
.


Dim NewArray As Variant
ReDim NewArray(5000)


.
.
.


For Each WrkSht In WrkShtCol

    For Each rw In WrkSht.Range(Antwortrange).Rows   'Reihen durchlaufen innerhalb der Antwortrange
    For Each cl In rw.Cells
        
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, SpaltenIndex).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    If lr = 2 And ws.Range("A1") = "" Then lr = 1
    'If lr = 2 And ws.Range("A2") = "" Then lr = 1
       
            If LCase(cl.Value) = "x" Then
                'cl.Offset(0, 9).Copy Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(lr, SpaltenIndex)
                NewArray(i) = cl.Offset(0, 9).Value & "|" & lr & "|" & SpaltenIndex
            End If
        Next cl
    Next rw
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(NewArray)
        
       ' lr = 'Midfunction
        'SpaltenIndex = Rightfunciton
       ' value = 'leftfunction
       
        Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(lr, SpaltenIndex) = Value
    Next i


.
.
..
atic

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried this but I dont understand what you mean with right/middle/left function

Comment: @leon Well. You can use a multidimensional array, which is a little bit more complex. Or you can use a onedimensional array. But in this case you must split your value with text operations. I.e. 
````
NewArray(i) = cl.Offset(0, 9).Value & "|" & lr & "|" & SpaltenIndex

MyPos1 = Instr(NewArray(i), "|")    'position of first seperator
MyPos2 = Instr(MyPos1, NewArray(i), "|")    'position of second seperator

lr = Mid(NewArray(i), MyPos1, MyPos2-Mypos1)    ' lr-wert.
SpaltenIndex = right(NewArray(i), Lenght(NewArray(i)-Mypos2) 'Spaltenindex
value = Left(NewArray(i), Mypos1) 'value
````